# Proof of and equality for Fibonacci sequence by induction

Tags: arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

[The equality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77fjU.jpg)

This is a question from "Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics".
I have the base case as 3.
I am new to induction so I can't seem to figure out the inductive step.
I tried putting values from one equality to another but it seems that is not the way to go.
Do I perhaps need to transpose stuff?

Comment: Note:  this is popularly known as [Cassini's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities).

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the note. Appreciated